# I want these csv files to be in parallel with each other but they are appending vertically. what's the error?

Tags: python, pandas, glob

```
filenames = glob.glob('readings/1/my sensor/level 1/*.csv')

dataframe = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames]

dataframe
```

my desired output is

```
            0           1         2          0         1           2



 0       0.187392  -0.133833  -0.299440  -0.636775  -0.176040  -0.293963
 1       0.187392   0.040151  -0.061984  -0.108058  -0.025899  -0.123201
 2       0.187070   0.094279   0.005998   0.002132   0.041117  -0.007212
 3       0.187392   0.133264   0.057871   0.029518   0.042406   0.034351
```

my code's output is

```
         0           1         2          
 0       0.187392  -0.133833  -0.299440  
 1       0.187392   0.040151  -0.061984  
 2       0.187070   0.094279   0.005998   
 3       0.187392   0.133264   0.057871   
          0           1         2         
 0       0.220900   0.382963   0.394240   
 1       0.221223   0.310792   0.272451   
 2       0.221545   0.292749   0.288561   
 3       0.221223   0.266007   0.290172
```

Comment: Because `pd.read_csv` is inside the list comp, you are telling it to create a new df for each file and store all those in a list

Comment: pd.concat(dataframe,axis=1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.concat`, something like:

```
dataframe = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames),axis=1)
```